# slick arrow at top of slide CSS

Tags: html, css, slider, position, slick.js

Hi it's my first time using slick carousel. I need to change the position of the arrow, so the arrow will be at the top level like the red arrow in the picture, and not at the side of the slider. I try using similar solution I find on the forum, but no one work for me.
I trying using position absolute and top properties but can't find the good CSS to fix this issue. I am trying to put the arrow in the class: `carousel_btn_arrow`

HTML

```
<div class="carousel_wrap">
    <div class="carousel_header">
        <div class="carousel_title typography__headline4">${Recommendation title}</div>

        <div class="carousel_btn_arrow">
           
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel_content">
    ${#Recommendation}
        <div class="product_grid_item" data-shortId="${shortId}" data-sku="${sku}">
            <a href="${url}">
                <div class="product_grid_item_img"><img src=${Image_url}></div>
            </a>
            <div class="product_grid_item_title typography__text1">${Name}</div>
            <div class="product_grid_item_price typography__text4">$${Price}</div>
    </div>
    ${/Recommendation}
        </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.carousel_wrap
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.carousel_header
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: var(--size-250);
}
.carousel_content
{
  display:flex;
  gap: var(--size-125);
}

.product_grid_item
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:var(--size-50);
}
.product_grid_item_img
{
  background: var(--color-grid-item-blend);
}

.product_grid_item_img img 
{
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.slick-slide
{
  margin-left: var(--size-125);
}


.slick-arrow
{

  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border:none;
}
.slick-arrow::before
{
  border: 0;
}
.slick-prev::before
{
  background: url("arrow_prev.svg") no-repeat center;
  margin-right: var(--size);
}
.slick-next::before
{
  background: url("arrow_next.svg") no-repeat center;
}
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".carousel_content").slick({
     arrows:true,
     slidesToShow: 3.99,
     slideToScroll: 1,
     infinite: true,
      prevArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-prev'></button>",
      nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next'></button>"
  });
  
});
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>

<div class="carousel_wrap">
    <div class="carousel_header">
        <div class="carousel_title typography__headline4">Heading</div>

        <div class="carousel_btn_arrow">
           
        </div>
    </div>

<div class="carousel_content">

<div class="product_grid_item" data-shortId="${shortId}" data-sku="${sku}">
    <a href="${url}">
        <div class="product_grid_item_img"><img src="makeup.jpg"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="product_grid_item_title typography__text1">abc</div>
    <div class="product_grid_item_price typography__text4">text</div>
</div>


<div class="product_grid_item" data-shortId="${shortId}" data-sku="${sku}">
    <a href="${url}">
        <div class="product_grid_item_img"><img src="makeup.jpg"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="product_grid_item_title typography__text1">abc</div>
    <div class="product_grid_item_price typography__text4">text</div>
</div>


<div class="product_grid_item" data-shortId="${shortId}" data-sku="${sku}">
    <a href="${url}">
        <div class="product_grid_item_img"><img src="makeup.jpg"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="product_grid_item_title typography__text1">abc</div>
    <div class="product_grid_item_price typography__text4">text</div>
</div>

<div class="product_grid_item" data-shortId="${shortId}" data-sku="${sku}">
    <a href="${url}">
        <div class="product_grid_item_img"><img src="makeup.jpg"></div>
    </a>
    <div class="product_grid_item_title typography__text1">abc</div>
    <div class="product_grid_item_price typography__text4">text</div>
</div>

</div>
</div>
```

Style

```
<style>
.carousel_wrap
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  
}
.carousel_header
{
  display:flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin-bottom: var(--size-250);
  padding-bottom: 40px;
}
.carousel_content
{
  display:flex;
  gap: var(--size-125);
}

.product_grid_item
{
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:column;
  gap:var(--size-50);
}
.product_grid_item_img
{
  background: var(--color-grid-item-blend);
  padding: 10px;
}

.product_grid_item_img img 
{
  mix-blend-mode: multiply;
}
.slick-slide
{
  margin-left: var(--size-125);
}

.slick-slide img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
.slick-arrow
{

  cursor: pointer;
  background: transparent;
  border:none;
}
.slick-arrow::before
{
  border: 0;
}
.slick-prev::before
{
  background: url("arrow_prev.svg") no-repeat center;
  margin-right: var(--size);
}
.slick-next::before
{
  background: url("arrow_next.svg") no-repeat center;
}

.slick-prev.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
font-size: 40px;
color: red !important;
right: 90px;
top: -40px;
    left: auto;
}
.slick-next.slick-arrow {
    position: absolute;
    font-size: 40px;
    color: red !important;
    right: 30px;
    top: -40px;
    left: auto;
}
</style>
```

JS

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $(".carousel_content").slick({
     arrows:true,
     slidesToShow: 3.99,
     slideToScroll: 1,
     infinite: true,
      prevArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-prev'> ← </button>",
      nextArrow:"<button type='button' class='slick-next'> → </button>"
  });
  
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Make yours independent arrows whenever you want them and then use slick dodumentation...

> prevArrow: string (html|jQuery selector) | object (DOM node|jQuery
> object)

So basically just make your arrows, add a specific ID or CLASS to each and then load it to slick as `prevArrow: $("specificIDorspecificClass")`